# How can I make a copy of the mandala on the right to be the one on the left on inkspace?

Tags: vector, drawing, laser-cutting

I was drawing a mandala using inkspace and when I tried to drag the objet I found a copy of it dragged with me which is the one on the left and I really don't know how did I do this. I want to laser cut it so I need it in the form which is on the left. I tried multiple to redo it but I failed, can anyone tell me how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Is that a raster image or a vector image?  How did you make it?  How was it constructed? Can you share the SVG?  It's hard to answer this with so few details. Sorry.  Please edit your question and provide more information. Thanks.

Comment: They are the same except for *one* of the outer shapes. I don't really understand what you are asking here.

Comment: The one on the left is not the same as the one on the right. Just guessing at how you got there but without more info it is difficult to tell. It looks to me like the one on the left is an expanded version of the one on the right which was made with a black stroke and white fill. Then the black shapes (previously the strokes) were deleted. The remaining white fills had a thin black stroke applied. Possibly the result of a boolean operation ?

Comment: @kyle sure but we could guess all day. The OP needs to add details about how this was made. I've voted to close it for now. There's not enough information to give a proper answer that isn't just a guess.

Comment: They are the same. it simply looks like a couple paths were missed during the copy.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the one on the left is a partial trace of the object on the right. Consider to duplicate the Path, Trace Bitmap feature of Inkscape. Check the preview options in the Trace dialog box to ensure you are getting the entire image.

Once traced, you'll want to confirm that you've selected the full vector assembly before dragging it to a new location. Also consider that you can select the image bounding box and move it instead of moving the vector. This will leave the entirety of the vector trace intact.

Answer (score 1):

Without having your problematic file only guessing is possible. Here's one:

Select all and apply Path > Combine. Then apply Path > Stroke to Path. Remove the fill color and apply a narrow stroke.

This assumes the image in the right is made of independent simple paths. This is useless if the image in the right is something more complex than guessed, for ex. it contains groups, path effects or clones.